Django + react with apache can't find django rest api
I have a django + react app that i wish to deploy on my VPS. I have installed apache and tried to configure it to work with django and react. When i only put django in the apache conf, it works with a curl command to the django api and react always works fine. However, when putting django and react together in the conf file in apache, it seems like when making posts or getting requests to the api, it doesn't find the django api.
Here is my app.conf in apache :
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName vps-*******.vps.ovh.net

    WSGIDaemonProcess app python-path=/home/gabriel/scanner:/home/gabriel/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup app

    WSGIScriptAlias /api /home/gabriel/scanner/App/wsgi.py

    <Directory /home/gabriel/scanner/App>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static /home/gabriel/scanner/staticfiles
    <Directory /home/gabriel/scanner/staticfiles>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /static-react /home/gabriel/scanner/frontend/build/static
    <Directory /home/gabriel/scanner/frontend/build/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/gabriel/scanner/frontend/build>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

CORS is allowed for all origins in my settings.py in django for testing and the whole settings.py file seems nicely configured. wsgy.py is nicely configured too and here is my urls.py :
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from backend import views
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/register/', views.register_user, name='register_user'),
    path('api/login/', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
    path('api/logout/', views.logout_user, name='logout_user'),
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('api/forgot-password/', views.forgot_password, name='forgot_password'),
    path('api/reset-password', views.reset_password, name='reset_password'),
    path('api/login-with-verificationcode', views.login_with_verificationcode, name='login_with_verifcode'),
    path('api/verify-code-then-login/', views.verify_code_then_login, name='verify_code_then_login'),
    path('api/scan/', views.ScanView.as_view(), name='scan_server'),
    path('api/check_superuser_exists/', views.check_superuser_exists, name='check_superuser_exists'),
    path('api/create_superuser/', views.create_superuser, name='create_superuser'),
    path('api/users/', views.UserListView.as_view(), name='user-list'),
    path('api/users/<str:username>/', views.UserDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete-user'),
    path('api/superuser/status/', views.CheckSuperUserStatusAPIView.as_view(), name='check-superuser-status'),
    path('api/userslist/', views.UserListView.as_view(), name='user-list'),
]

finally, here is the error i get in my browser console when frontend calls django api:
XHRPOST http://vps-******.vps.ovh.net/api/create_superuser/ [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 616ms]
I tried several configurations in Apache but none of them works...When i try other confs in apache it seems like react is interfering with django
Do you guys have an idea of where my problem comes from ?
I am new to all this thank you for your help !
